# sort a list of lists in python with key in .sort() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list of lists like:

```py
myList = [
    ["name1", [12, 89]],
    ["name2", [37, 2]],
    ["name3", [5, 4]],
    ["name4", [67, 998]]
]
```

- The first element inside the inner list is the name
- The second element inside the inner list is another list with two numbers

I want to use the `sort()` method to sort the list by:

1. Name
2. number1
3. number2

For example, for the first element, sort by:

1. "name1"
2. 12
3. 89

Can this be achieved with lambda functions?

To sort by name I did: `myList.sort(key = lambda x: x)`

How can I use lambda functions to sort by 2. and 3. (the numbers)

**Desired Output**

- Sort by "Name" gives:

```py
myList = [
    ["name1", [12, 89]],
    ["name2", [37, 2]],
    ["name3", [5, 4]],
    ["name4", [67, 998]]
]
```

- Sort by "Number1" gives:

```py
myList = [
    ["name3", [5, 4]],
    ["name1", [12, 89]],
    ["name2", [37, 2]],
    ["name4", [67, 998]]
]
```

- Sort by "Number2" gives:

```py
myList = [
    ["name2", [37, 2]],
    ["name3", [5, 4]],
    ["name1", [12, 89]],
    ["name4", [67, 998]]
]
```

Comment: `lambda x: x` is the *identity function*, it's pointless using that as a key. What you're describing sounds like the default sort anyway, it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I only used it to sort by name

Comment: Could you also show your **EXACT** desired output for the list? What does sorting by  `Name, number1, number2` mean?

Comment: But it doesn't do that. The fact that you end up sorting by the name anyway is because that's how sequences sort by default.

Comment: @Countour-Integral just added the desired output for each sort case

Comment: I tried to use lambda function like so: ```lambda x: myList[x][0]``` to sort by ```number1``` but got ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list```

Comment: Wait, are you asking how to do each of three entirely separate sorting operations, or are you asking how to sort by name, breaking ties by first number, breaking *those* ties by second number?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am asking how to do each of three entirely separate sorting operations

Comment: @Kartikeya It's confusing because you used `myListSorted` as the name of three different outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with lambdas. Given that your list is

```py
myList = [
    ["name1", [12, 89]],
    ["name2", [37, 2]],
    ["name3", [5, 4]],
    ["name4", [67, 998]]
]
```

- **Sort by "Name"**, you sort them alphabetically because `ord('1') < ord('2')` is `True`.

```py
# check the 0th element which is the string for each row
myList.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

- Sort by **"Number1"**, you just use `x[1][0]` to access the 0th number of the array in the 1st index

```py
# Take as key the x[1][0] element
myList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][0])
```

Similarly with **"Number2"**

```py
myList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][1])
```

Comment: @John D Do what in 1 call? Sort the list 3 times?